# How to phrase "I like the way you think" in Latin?

Tags: idiom, english-to-latin-translation

Is there a concise way to phrase "I like the way you think" in Latin?
I can find ways to say this, but everything I could think of is a little unwieldy compared to the English.
For example, I might say: *Mi placet modus, quo cogitas*.

Is it possible to do this with the verb, or should I be using a noun instead?
With a noun I can make it flow better: *Mihi placet cogitatio tua.*
However, I am far from sure that I have hit upon the best way to phrase such things.

If anyone is familiar with a Latin idiom or other natural sounding wording of "I like the way you think" or something similar enough, I would be glad to hear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though this suggestion won't work in every context, it works in an important one. "I like the way you think" can be a general compliment, but (to my ear, at least) often applies to a situation where someone is suggesting a course of action.

In Plautus's *Poenulus* I.1, after hearing a plan from Milphio, Agorastocles assents to the plan by saying:

> **Consilium placet!**

This basically means, "Sounds like a plan!" but could also be creatively translated as, "I like the way you think!"

Answer (score 7):

In his *De officiis*, Cicero wrote (my highlighting):

> Si quis ab ineunte aetate habet causam celebritatis et nominis aut a patre acceptam aut aliquo casu atque fortuna, in hunc oculi ombium coniciuntur. **Eius** vita ac **modus agendi** examinantur et, tamquam in clarissima luce versetur, nullum nec dictum nec factum eius obscurum potest esse.

(translation, using the third person plural to maintain gender ambivalence)

> If someone has reason to be celebrated and famous from their earliest youth, either received from their father or by some chance and fortune, everyone's eyes are on them. Their life and **their way of doing things** are examined and, just as if they were in the brightest light, none of their words or actions can be obscure.

Furthermore, after a quick search, it seems that when the subject of *mihi/tibi/... placet* is a proper noun (*modus* here) - as opposed to a substantivized verb -  the *mihi/tibi... placet* bit goes at the end of the sentence more frequently than not.

As a result of these observations, I think it's safe to say the phrasing

*Tuus modus cogitandi mihi placet*

is quite natural.

Answer (score 0):

One option is *gaudeo in ideis tuis*.

It is "sort of" expressing the same thing, using *ideis*, which is nice (multilingual, English/Spanish at least).

As Vincenzo states, *ideis* as ideas is of a modern use. For a more Classical tone (even though you did not specify a tag), *cogitationibus* would be a better word.

Comment: _idea_ doesn't seem to have in Latin the meaning it developed in modern languages. It either was used in the context of philosophy, or with the meaning of "notion" - the latter use may be limited to Church Latin, in fact.

Comment: On a second thought, the usual construct is "_gaudeo_ + abl. of cause", is this some sort of special case?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Joonas did not specify a tag with period. But I added a more classical tone. Regarding your second question, [it seems](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=gaudeo) accusative are not so common, but are still attested.

Comment: Yes, though I think even in modern times _idea_ isn't the same as the English "idea". Ah, nice to know _gaudeo_ can be used with other cases - though one ought to check whether "in" is the right proposition for the accusative, since I don't see such an instance on the page you linked.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Oh, but I think you are right. Here it should be the ablative and not the accusative. See the quotation [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idea#Noun_10). I think _idea_ truly meant idea.

Comment: I see. I found an instance of "gaudeo in + ablative" in St. Paul's Epistle to the Colossians; the absolute ablative could also be used. The quotation on Wiktionary is indeed of philosophical nature ("doctrine of ideas"), but don't worry about it.